# Is it possible to use a function to set the rows property value?

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using Solr 7.4 and I would like to add an upper limit to the rows property. The goal is to get it through the `solrconfig.xml` file.

My Solr instance is accessed by multiple systems so I would like to use the `<invariants/>` or `<append/>` sections to set this limitation logic as default to prevent any overload (like a query setting `&rows=1000000`).

Considering the upper limit as 20 results:

- `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*`--> return 20 results (upper limit as default value)
- `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&rows=5` --> return 5 results because 5 is lower than the upper limit (5 < 20)
- `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&rows=30` --> return 20 results because 30 is greater than the upper limit (30 > 20)

So, I am trying to use [the `min()` function](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/function-queries.html#min-function) to implement it. But as [solr parses the `rows` property as an Integer](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/7.4.0/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/QParser.java#L274), if I set anything else than a numeric value, it throws a `NumberFormatException`, which is the case if I search using `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&rows=min(5, 20)` for instance.

PS: the same function syntax works if I use it for the `fl` field: `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&fl=testField:min(5, 20)` shows `"testField":5` in the results.

Is there a way to set the function result as the rows value instead of it's text?

Comment: That should probably be the task of your controller. The functions are applied to _fields in a document_. They're not applied to request parameters that only decide how large the slice to return should be.

Comment: Mmm;. the problem is that you'd have to use `{!func}` here for solr to properly parse `min()`, but this QParser is meant to work with query and query filter parameters `q` and `qf`. You could still compute the rows value beforehand if it doesn't depend on field values from the index.

Comment: @MatsLindh Well I actually would like to set is as default, so regardless who is querying Solr it would have this rows limit. @EricLavault it would depend only on the rows property, it would be `<str name="rows">min($rows, 20)</str>` but in this case there's an infinite recursion issue